# formatting date in rails outputs null hour minutes and seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I am trying to reformat date, so I put this

```
Date.strptime("2009-04-24 18:33:41", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

but this outputs null hours, minutes and seconds

```
 "04/24/2009 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're using `Date` to parse a "date time" string.  Use `Time`, or `DateTime` instead which don't ignore the time part.  Also, remove `%Z` from format in `strptime` as keeping that is going to result in Argument Error because your input date does not have zone information.

```
Time.strptime("2009-04-24 18:33:41", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```